# S3 not responding in a timely manner to plupload in IE9 with flash runtime

Tags: amazon-s3, plupload

Ok, so the question should be clear just from the title.

I'm uploading directly to S3 from plupload 2 beta.

Chrome/Firefox/Safari, of course, are all ok.

IE9 completes the upload - it appears in the bucket, everything is fine, but eventually plupload returns an error. When I watch the network activity through Fiddler2, you can see the request to s3 does not get a response for a looooong time. Well after the progress through plupload has hit 100%.

When the response come back, plupload has branded the file as 'FAILED' (code 4) even though the file has actually completed.

So, to summarise, the file upload **does complete** but plupload doesn't get a response (quick enough?) from s3 and errors out.

[Code is here](https://gist.github.com/cbiggins/5113812).

**EDIT:** So it looks like the progress is hitting 100 but the waiting time is the file actually uploading. The problem seems to be plupload throwing an error for a correctly uploaded file.